# Converting VB.NET code to C#: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates

Okay, so I've got I got a VB project that I'm converting to C#. So far, so good. The problem is delegates/actions are quite different between the two languages and I'm struggling to work out the difference.

```
Private methods As New Dictionary(Of Integer, [Delegate])

Private Sub Register(id As Integer, method As [Delegate])
    methods.Add(id, method)
End Sub

Private Sub LogName(name As String)
    Debug.Print(name)
End Sub

Private Sub Setup()
    Register(Sub(a As String) LogName(a))
End Sub
```

And in C#

```
private Dictionary<int, Delegate> methods;

private void Register(int id, Delegate method)
{
    methods.Add(id, method);
}

private void LogName(string name)
{
    Debug.Print(name);
}

private void Setup()
{
    Register((string a) => LogName(a));
}
```

The last line above is causing the `CS1660  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type` error.

Comment: did you tried `Register(new Action((string a) => LogName(a)));` or `Register(new Action((string a) => { LogName(a); }));`

Comment: Yep, no go. Variation of the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your register method should be defined as:

```
private void Register(int id, Action<string> method)
{
    methods.Add(id, method);
}
```

Or you need to explicitly wrap your lambda in an `Action`:

```
private void Setup()
{
    Register(5, new Action<string>((string a) => LogName(a)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, 2nd part is the solution.

Comment: A cast will also work: Register(0, (Action<string>)((string a) => LogName(a)));